# link menu adm subscriber wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I put a link in the adm panel menu that a user with subscriber permission can view?

[image]

Comment: What should that link do? Should they access a page in the admin view. Or are they gonna go to another page on the site?

Comment: It is redirected to another page, a restricted page of the client, so I need a link there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with the function below

```
function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
   add_menu_page( 'Custom Menu Page Title', 'Acesso Documentos', 'comprador', 
   '/documentos', '', 'dashicons-download', 2 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );
```